# Update an Activity Edit text from the adapter

Tags: android

I have a `MainActivity` that uses a `RecyclerView` with an `Adapter`. I would like to update the `Textview` title from the `Adapter` class. When the user clicks on the `CheckBox` within the `CardView` that is in the `RecyclerView`.

Clicking and getting the info work well but I don't know how to access the `TextView` title from the `Adapter` class to be able to update the info any time the user clicks on the check box and changes the info.

So, my problem is, how to access title `TextView` from `Adapter` class?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Menu_21RutinaMati">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titol"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_View"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put that adapter in activity class or make static object of that textview or pass textview in constructor of adapter

Comment: You have to pass item click callback from the adapter to Activity.  Declare 1 interface & implement that in the activity. and call it from the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Kotlin, I'd do something like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        recycler_View.adapter = YourAdapter() { checkboxClicked ->
            titol.text = if(checkboxClicked) "firstTitle" else "secondTitle"
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
class YourAdapter(private val onCheckboxClicked: (Boolean) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter() {

...

override onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) {
    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater
    .from(parent.context)
    .inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, parent, false)
    .apply {
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked -> onCheckboxClicked(isChecked) }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define an interface in your adapter:

```
public interface onItemClickListener{
      void onClick(String title, Long id);//pass your object types.
}
```

and define this interface in adapter and initialize in adapter

```
 onItemClickListener onItemClickListner;

      public void setOnItemClickListener(adapter.onItemClickListener 
      onItemClickListner) 
      {
      this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
      }
```

in "onClickListener" method for cardview, use the interface object:

```
holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onItemClickListner.onClick(model.getTitle(),model.getId());
        }
        });
```

now let's go to the activity
after defining your adapter object,implement interface method like  this

```
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(context,list);
     adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new adapter.onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String title, Long id) {
            txt.setText(title);
           
        }
     });
```

hope this helps you!